# Why doesnt .textContent work in this situation? Cant gain access to textContent on html that is generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a variable called 'newItem' which essentially is a block of html code that will be appended directly to the dom when activated (this code is for a javascript shopping cart). I have the line of 1

below and am trying to access the textContent of 'amount-items' on the very last div (class='dropDown-price') as indicated by Number(amountItems.textContent) but am left with a null on the console.

What am i doing wrong, why doesnt .textContent gain access to the '1' for the 'amount-items' class?

Thanks for any help i can get

```
//dropdown menu hidden
const cartDropdown = document.querySelector('.cart-dropDown-items');

//every single + symbol
const addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');

//price of item
const foodPrices = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-row-title');

//name of item
const foodNames = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-row-foodName');

//weight of item
const foodWeights = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-row-weight');

const items = [];
let total = 0;

for (let i=0; i<addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
        addToCartButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            const newItem = document.createElement('div');
            newItem.className = 'dropDown-item';
            let amountItems = document.querySelector('.amount-items');

        newItem.innerHTML =                 
            `<div class='dropDown-title dropDown-info'>
                ${foodNames[i].innerHTML}
            </div>
            <div class='dropDown-amount dropDown-info'>
                <p class='amount-items'>1</p>
            </div>
            <div class='dropDown-price dropDown-info'>
                ${Number(foodPrices[i].innerHTML.substring(1)) * Number(amountItems.textContent)}
            </div>`;

        console.log(newItem)
        // if item currently exists in array, just update amount in checkout and increase count++
        if (items.includes(addToCartButtons[i].value)) {
            items.push(addToCartButtons[i].value);
            for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].includes(addToCartButtons[i].value)) {
                    Number(amountItems.innerHTML) + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        // if items does not exist in array, update dom with new item UI and count = 1 by default
        else {
            items.push(addToCartButtons[i].value);
            cartDropdown.appendChild(newItem);


         }
         console.log(items)
    })
}
```

Comment: let amountItems = document.querySelector('.amount-items');
can you console log amountItems after this line and see if it is null

Comment: @ChamalPerera its null

Comment: You are getting amountItems before it is being created on the DOM it seems.

Comment: @ChamalPerera any idea on how to fix this? if i can just get this to work, i can figure everything else out. Thank you

Comment: instead of innerHTML append each div to newItem. see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

before the last div you can get the amountItems.
then it won't be null.

Comment: display html and css on your question...

Comment: @ChamalPerera trying now.

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej take a look at my prev post on my profile. has html and css for this.